# python selenium chrome - extensions with headless not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, headless

I have:

- selenium v4
- chrome v77
- chromedriver v77

Do chrome extensions work in headless mode?

This thread from 2016:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=604324

And this one from 2017: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2071

These two articles suggest **chromedrive does not support headless mode with extensions?**
Is this still true? Firefox does support headless with extensions ......

**Please note** I do not want to assign a profile with: `ops.add_argument('user-data-dir=path_to_profile')`. This should allow the solution. But I need the solution to work in threads ... without duplicating and assigning profiles manually to each thread.

Here is my code:

```
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
#///////////////// Init binary & driver
new_binary_path = 'D:/path/Selenium_Test/chrome/chrome_exe/installed _32/chrome.exe'
new_driver_path = 'D:/path/Selenium_Test/chrome/chromedriver77_32.exe'
new_addon_path = r'D:\path\Selenium_Test\chrome\chrome_exe\uBlock.crx'

#///////////////// Init headless
serv = Service(new_driver_path)
ops = options()
ops.binary_location = new_binary_path
ops.add_argument("--headless")
#ops.headless = True (TRIED THIS -- doesnt work)
ops.add_extension(new_addon_path)
#ops.add_argument("--load-extension="+new_addon_path) (TRIED THIS -- doesnt work)

#///////////////// Init Browser
print('establishing 1st browser...')
browser1 = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(service=serv, options=ops)
browser1.set_page_load_timeout(int(load_page_timeout))
```

**stacktrace:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: failed to wait for extension background page to load: chrome-extension://cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm/background.html
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm/background.html
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x003FEB13+1501971]
    Ordinal0 [0x0037F6D1+980689]
    Ordinal0 [0x0030765F+489055]
    Ordinal0 [0x002F84FA+427258]
    Ordinal0 [0x0029C0D0+49360]
    Ordinal0 [0x002B9800+169984]
    Ordinal0 [0x002B942D+169005]
    Ordinal0 [0x002B78EB+162027]
    Ordinal0 [0x002A0AC7+68295]
    Ordinal0 [0x002A1B40+72512]
    Ordinal0 [0x002A1AD9+72409]
    Ordinal0 [0x00398F37+1085239]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0049D7ED+503293]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0049D580+502672]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x004A46AC+531644]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0049DFFA+505354]
    Ordinal0 [0x00390606+1050118]
    Ordinal0 [0x0039047F+1049727]
    Ordinal0 [0x0039AF9B+1093531]
    Ordinal0 [0x0039B103+1093891]
    Ordinal0 [0x0039A095+1089685]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76806359+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77427B74+228]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77427B44+180]
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a super old question but I was struggling with the same issue until recently (2023) they upgraded the headless chrome which now allows headless to work with extensions. See webpage for more details (https://developer.chrome.com/articles/new-headless/)

Just replace the headless option above with the below.

ops.add_argument('--headless=new')

According to the website if you just use --headless is still uses the old version and you have to explicitly point it to the new version to work.

Comment: If someone would like to check if this answer is correct ... in the mean time I'm going to mark its correct .... comment here if it is not correct, or edit the post ....... as I'm not currently coding this project anymore